# Frequency Seaborn Countplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is some basic example of code :

```
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", hue="who", data=titanic)
```

[image]

What I would like to have is just the hist of frequency of let's say man, for each label of the variable "class".

For example, for "class"="First", we should have a proportion of men equals to something like 110/(110+90+5) .

Is it possible with seaborn? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to divide the counts of only men by the the total counts of the dataframe grouped by the `"class"`. (Note that seaborn is only used to load the dataset here.)

```
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

df1 = titanic.groupby("class").size()
df2 = titanic[titanic["who"] == "man"].groupby("class").size()

(df2/df1).plot.bar(title="Proportion of men on titanic", color="C0")
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do it with only one color for every bins? Like everything in blue? Thanks by the way

Comment: Sure use the `color` argument.